# Localization of app-owned Open Graph objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

The localization procedure for Open Graph is tightly coupled to HTTP.  There is a magical facebook HTTP-header or URL parameter given when scraping which should be used to change the value of localized data.

When using app-owned objects, the object is simply created using JSON.  The question I have is: how do I localize an app-owned object?

Here is an example of the creation of an app-owned object.  What can I do to localize the title?

```
$ curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/mynamespace:myobject" \
       -F "$ACCESS" \
       -F 'object = { "title" : "My Unlocalized Title",
                      "image" : "https://example.com/myimage.png",
                      "url"   : "https://example.com/myobject" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android an **id** is returned in the Callback. Then I think you can use this **id** to localize the title. Sorry if I dont answer your question.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/#hosted